# How can I efficiently return two indexed elements from a search over many large documents?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a marklogic (4.2) database that contains tens of thousands of
large-ish, complex-ish (some are smaller, but the big ones are 10MB+)
documents, which are being searched using a fairly complex, programmatically
constructed search:search call. In normal use, returning a few results at a
time using pagination, and generating snippets of the matches, it works
fine. Now one of the client developers has a need to return *all* the
results from that query at once, even in the case where he's constructed a
query that returns all the documents in the DB. He doesn't care about most
of the content of the matches though; just a couple of ID elements (one
numeric, and one free-text), both of which are indexed, and both are always
at the same xpath in the document.

The thing is, I can't come up with an efficient way of querying two elements
across a dataset that large; it always needs to load the whole document and
the query just disappears off into the long grass doing that a few tens of
thousands of times, and basically never returns.

I've tried using the element-value lexicon on one of the elements, filtered
by the search. That returns quickly, but has a  couple of downsides:
* it returns false-positives. That's not necessarily a deal-breaker, but is
  sub-optimal.
* it only gets one of the elements; as soon as I try to iterate that list
  and fetch the other element he's interested in, it unsurprisingly takes
  forever (because we're back to loading the whole document for every
  match.)

I've wondered if declaring a field containing those two elements might help
(I could use the lexicon to get at one of the values, and then look for it
in the field, rather than loading whole documents just to get at one ID,)
but I've never used fields before, and it looks like they're always word
queries, not element ones, which doesn't sound ideal for the sort of thing
I'd need to do with them.

I've also thought maybe creating a new element in the document, that
contains an encoded form of both IDs would allow me to create one index
containing both and then use the lexicon approach I mentioned above to
narrow it down to documents that at least match the unfiltered search. That
feels like a pretty hacky approach though.

What I'm really looking for is a way to say "here's a search, here are the
(indexed) elements I'm interested in, now get their values for matching
documents". Is there a way to do that?

I have a feeling the answer is "no", but it's worth asking.

If there isn't, does anyone have suggestions about what alternative
approaches might work best?

Thanks.

---

## Example of the document format:

```
<doc:entity>
  <doc:metadata>
    <doc:sap-metadata>
      <doc:info>
        <doc:id>12345678</doc:id>
        <doc:number>AS-1990 13:45</doc:number>
        <!-- more document info here -->
      </doc:info>
    </doc:sap-metadata>
  </doc:metadata>
  <doc:content>
    <!-- a lot of text content here... -->
  </doc:content>
</doc:entity>
```

## Search code (first cut):

The search code is nothing cleverreally; just a standard search:search
call with a search term and (at least one constraint - I'm sticking to the
simple case for clarity):

```
search:search(fn:concat("relevant:1 ", $search-term), $search-options)
```

`$search-term` is a plaintext search provided by the user. `$search-options` is
quite a lot of xml, but I don't think contains anything exotic; just a bunch
of constraint and facet definitions and custom snippet, generated by:

```
declare function func:do-snippet(
  $result as node(),
  $ctsquery as schema-element(cts:query),
  $options as element(search:transform-results)?
) as element(search:snippet)
{
  element search:snippet{
    element search:match {
      fn:doc(xdmp:node-uri($result))/doc:entity/doc:metadata/doc:sap-metadata/doc:info/doc:id,
      fn:doc(xdmp:node-uri($result))/doc:entity/doc:metadata/doc:sap-metadata/doc:info/doc:number
    }
  }
};
```

## Search code (second cut):

This one is using the element-value-lexicon on id to generate a list of IDs
that match the search term (unfiltered, obviously) and then using that id to
query the doc number:

```
let $query := ...
let $options := ...
for $id in cts:element-values(fn:QName("http://my.document.namespace", "id"), (), (), cts:query(search:parse($query, $options)))
  return element document {
    attribute id {$id},
    attribute number {
      cts:element-values(fn:QName("http://my.document/namespace", "number"), (), (), cts:element-value-query(fn:QName("http://my.document.namespace", "id"), $id ))
    }}
```

That first `cts:element-values` call returns nice and quickly, but iterating
over the response and doing another `cts:element-values` for each of them is
really slow.

Comment: Can you provide some sample docs (snippets), and the code you used to search through it. I'm sure there are optimizations possible..

Comment: Added inline in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches you could try: streaming results, co-occurrences, and encoded lexicon values.

You've already touched on encoded lexicon values, and I think that would be the most efficient approach. It may feel like a hack, but it's the moral equivalent of a function-based index. It should scale well.

Also using range indexes and lexicon functions would be `cts:element-value-co-occurrences`. This won't scale quite as well as encoded values, but it's less work up front. Be sure to consider the 'map' option, too: http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-co-occurrences

Finally you could simply give the developer what he wants. Use `search:parse` to parse the query as normal, or build it using `cts:query` constructors. Then call `cts:search` to get the matching nodes and return them. The results will be large, but that's inevitable. You may run into `XDMP-EXPNTREECACHEFULL` errors: take a look at http://blakeley.com/blogofile/2012/03/19/let-free-style-and-streaming/ for one way around those. It may require some tricky coding on both sides, but this lets you return arbitrarily large result sequences.

Comment: Brilliant; thanks! `element-value-co-occurrences` is exactly what I was looking for (well, not quite exactly; it would be better if it was filtered but magically just as fast). I'll certainly bear your other thoughts in mind in case we hit performance problems in the future, but for now that has a worst case execution time of c. 7 seconds, which is OK. Sadly, the map option isn't available until ML 5, so no joy for me there; not a big deal.

Comment: The map option isn't documented in 4.2, but try it anyway. It probably works.

Comment: Great advice +10 by mblakele 
I will add a general coorelary.  The way you describe your use case, I believe should be satisfiable *entirely* from indexes.  (ie. if the results are only atomic values of elements/attributes).   In general, if you can construct an index, and a query that is designed for ONLY indexes, and if the conditions are also entirely resolved by index alone -- you can then do what you want in roughly constant time independent of  corpus size.  
( implementation left as an excersize to the reader :) 
--->  THIS is the core of many 'advanced query' topics in the manual.